# Twitter bootstrap integration with easyUI

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-easyui

Can someone share his experience on using Easy UI and BootStrap together? just want to know if i will face any compatibility issue using them together?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What you have tried so for?

Comment: well, i was just exploring the features in both and i like some feature to be useful for me in both API's. so just want to confirm before digging in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen EasyUI in any modern webdev app. Looks outdated, something which was nice to play around in a world before HTML5,CSS3 and Boostrap and maybe still considered for fastcoding a simple UI. But Bootstrap + some well selected .js libraries make the difference. So leave EasyUI where it is and do not think about combining it with Bootstrap, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Sure, it is basically a philosophical question and a question of your skillset to use a library dated from 2010 which has less to offer then bootstrap and besides a minifeed size 389kb!!. Dont get me wrong, you can use it and it might help to get some quick UI forms done. But it is like using a nokia s3 when everyone else goes for a iphone 7.